# Unit Tests with Moq getting an error ""An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments""

Tags: asp.net-core

I am writing Unit Tests with Moq when I suddenly encountered this error message while typing one of my Async methods:

"An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments"

However, when I was looking at my existing code, I was calling the code with just 1 argument.

Async Method definition:

public virtual async Task> Async(Guid fileId, MemoryStream stream = null)

```
        scope.MyMock.Setup(x => x.Async(fileId)).Returns(Task.FromResult(Result.Ok(new ValidationResult())));
```

Gives me an error: "An expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments". Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass all arguments, even if they have a default value. In your case, the argument `stream` has a default value of `null`, but you still need to pass it.

So you could have this:

```
scope.MyMock.Setup(x => x.Async(fileId, null)).ReturnsAsync(Result.Ok(new ValidationResult()));
```

Comment: Can I use  "It.IsAny<MemoryStream>() " instead of null? Like :                  
scope.MyMock.Setup(x => x.Async(fileId, It.IsAny<MemoryStream>())).ReturnsAsync(Result.Ok(new ValidationResult()));

Comment: @Osheca Yeah I think that would be even better!

Comment: Thank you for your time.